# git checkout to other branch if files can be overridden to existing branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I want to change my branch from `branch1` to `branch2`
but changes of `branch1` is overriding changes of `branch2` so git is not allowing me to checkout 
note : I don't want to commit changes to `branch1` 
commands I have tried

```
git checkout branch2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [git stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) is what you need. `git stash` will take your outstanding changes and record them in git's data directory, then revert the directory to a clean state. Then you can `git checkout branch2` and `git stash pop` to get your changes back.

Comment: stash works properly, but is there any other work around? Like committing changes to temp branch.

Comment: Stash does exactly this.

Comment: You can do it with a temp branch: `git checkout -b temp-branch; git commit -am "temp"; git checkout branch2; git cherry-pick temp-branch; git branch -D temp-branch; git reset HEAD~`, but that's pretty much what `git stash` does and takes a lot more work.